# The element is not attached - Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying scraping data from a number of pages on a website by using `selenium` in `python`. The syntax run and **scrape** data successfully on the first page but, after the second page, it can't find the click button and stop scraping. I check the [HTML codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHjeB.jpg) of the webpage, but the element on the second page is as same as the one on the first page. I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36013135/python-with-selenium-element-is-not-attached-to-the-page-document/36013523) related to the same issue. I think that the problem is caused by that the reference to the button is lost after the `DOM` is changed, but I still can't fix the issue properly. I would appreciate any suggestions or solutions. The syntax and results are included below:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\...\chromedriver.exe")
browser.get('https://fortune.com/global500/2019/walmart')

table = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('tbody')

data =[]

#Use For Loop for Index

i = 1
while True:
    if i > 5:
        break
    try:
        print("Scraping Page no. " + str(i))
        i = i + 1
        
        # Select rows in the table
        for row in table.find_elements_by_css_selector('tr'):
            cols = data.append([cell.text for cell in row.find_elements_by_css_selector('td')])

        try:
            WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//span[@class="singlePagination__icon--2KbZn"]')))
            time.sleep(10)
        finally:
            browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="singlePagination__icon--2KbZn"]').click()
     
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break


data1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Labels','Value'])

print(data1)

browser.close()
```

**output**:

```
Scraping Page no. 1
Scraping Page no. 2
Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
 (Session info: chrome=....)

                     Labels                    Value
0                      (...)                   (...)
1                      (...)                   (...)
```

Comment: The only difference between this question and [this previous one of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60425584/the-element-is-not-attached-to-the-dom-selenium-in-python) is the formatting of a single link.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The element is not attached to the DOM, selenium in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60425584/the-element-is-not-attached-to-the-dom-selenium-in-python)

Comment: Sorry, it's actually the formatting of a few links. In any case, they're virtually identical.

Comment: fyi it's __scrape__ (and __scraper__, __scraped__, __scraping__) not scrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move `table = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('tbody')` line into your `while` loop.So that you will get the latest reference to the table element as part of each loop and then you should not see any stale element issue.

```
while True:
    table = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('tbody')
    if i > 5:
```