# How do I grab the alt text from this webpage I'm trying to scrape with selenium and scrapy

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

I have code that runs through the data in a csv and searches for the names on that csv and then filters through scrapy to grab the email on each of these search pages.

Please ignore my poor code. If you have any comments for how to make it better, then that would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
from email import header
import email
from posixpath import split
from sqlite3 import Row
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import csv
from emails_on_site import EmailsSpider
from platform import python_branch
import re
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from platform import python_branch
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from platform import python_branch
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
import re

engine = 'python'

url_list = []
email_list = []

email_file = "emails.csv"
engine = 'python'
contacts = []

pattern = re.compile(r"[\w\.]+@[\w\.]+")

chrome_options = Options() 

chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

s=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=chrome_options)

driver.implicitly_wait(3)

URL = "http://www.directory.ucla.edu/search.php"

#update URL
driver.get(URL)
page = requests.get(URL)

#update info below
m = driver.find_element(By.ID, "q")

providers = open("names.csv")
data = csv.reader(providers)

def goLeft():
    m.send_keys(Keys.LEFT)
    m.send_keys(Keys.LEFT)
    m.send_keys(Keys.LEFT)
    m.send_keys(Keys.LEFT)
    m.send_keys(Keys.LEFT)
    m.send_keys(Keys.LEFT)
    m.send_keys(Keys.LEFT)
    m.send_keys(Keys.LEFT)
    m.send_keys(Keys.LEFT)
    m.send_keys(Keys.LEFT)
    m.send_keys(Keys.LEFT)
    m.send_keys(Keys.LEFT)
    m.send_keys(Keys.LEFT)
    m.send_keys(Keys.LEFT)
    m.send_keys(Keys.LEFT)
    m.send_keys(Keys.LEFT)
    m.send_keys(Keys.LEFT)
    m.send_keys(Keys.LEFT)
    m.send_keys(Keys.LEFT)
    m.send_keys(Keys.LEFT)
    m.send_keys(Keys.LEFT)
    m.send_keys(Keys.LEFT)
    m.send_keys(Keys.LEFT)
    m.send_keys(Keys.LEFT)
    m.send_keys(Keys.LEFT)
    m.send_keys(Keys.LEFT)
    m.send_keys(Keys.LEFT)
    m.send_keys(Keys.LEFT)
    m.send_keys(Keys.LEFT)
    m.send_keys(Keys.LEFT)


class EmailsSpider(CrawlSpider):
    
    name = 'emails'

    # change the below URLS

    allowed_domains = ['directory.ucla.edu/search.php']
    start_urls = ['http://www.directory.ucla.edu/search.php']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=''), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        emails = re.findall('[\w\.]+@[\w\.]+' , response.text)
        names = re.findall('^([A-Za-z \-]{2,25})+$', response.text)
        for email in emails:
            yield {
                'Email': email
                }
                    
        print(names)
        print(emails)

for row in data:
    m.send_keys(str(row))

    
    m.send_keys(Keys.BACK_SPACE)
    m.send_keys(Keys.BACK_SPACE)
    goLeft()
    m.send_keys(Keys.RIGHT)
    m.send_keys(Keys.RIGHT)
    m.send_keys(Keys.BACK_SPACE)
    m.send_keys(Keys.BACK_SPACE)    

    m.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(3)    
    try:

        EmailsSpider
    except:
        contacts.append(str(row) + "was unable to be found")
    print(contacts)
    time.sleep(2)
    m.clear()
    iter(row)
    continue
```

Here's the CSV:

```
Nicole Green
Clark Kent
Steve Ballmer
Elon Musk
```

Here's the example html I'm trying to automate scraping:

```
<div class="email">
<a href="mailto:ngreen%40caps.ucla.edu">
<img src="/img/email.png" alt="ngreen@caps.ucla.edu">
</a>
</div>
```

How do I scrape that alt text in the img tag?

I've tried: [this]https://medium.com/swlh/web-scraping-with-selenium-scrapy-9d9c2e9d83b1, [this] https://scrapeops.io/python-scrapy-playbook/scrapy-selenium/, [and this][Python with Selenium "element is not attached to the page document"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36013135/python-with-selenium-element-is-not-attached-to-the-page-document)

Answer (score 0):

Load and save lines from CSV, I think you can. Here is a simple example of how to get an email

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_email(name):
    url = "http://www.directory.ucla.edu/search.php"
    payload = f'querytype=person&q={name}&searchtype=basic'
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
    }
    response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    if 'Your search did not return any results. Please try again' in response.text:
        return None
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    return [email.find('a').get_text() for email in soup.find('td', class_='element-leftbar').find_all('div')
            if email.find('label', string='Email')]


users = ['Nicole Green', 'Clark Kent', 'Steve Ballmer', 'Elon Musk', 'Choi Jhongrack']
for user in users:
    print(user, get_email(user))
```

OUTPUT:

```
Nicole Green ['ngreen@caps.ucla.edu']
Clark Kent None
Steve Ballmer None
Elon Musk None
Choi Jhongrack ['jhongrackchoi@mednet.ucla.edu']
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: "return [email.find('a').get_text() for email in soup.find('td', class_='element-leftbar').find_all('div')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'" and also the CSV data is inputting like this: "['Hope Levin'] None" how do I get rid of the "['']"? Thanks!

Comment: @Tom which version Python and bs4 installed on ur PC?